# Trying to get pass property updates from objects to gui via data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

So I have a simple wpf application that I'm using as practice.
It's based on the idea of a zoo, and I have 3 animal type (elephant, giraffe, monkey).

Each of these have a health property & a IsDead property.

Both of these properties are part of the Animal class to which my Elephant class, Giraffe class & Monkey class all inherit from.

I want to be able to change the health field as an example and update a listview with these values.

So far none of the items created are being updated on screen. I know it'll be something simple but any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

View:

```
<ListView Margin="5"
          Name="lstMonkey"
          Width="150"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeyList}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Index" />
        <!-- DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=}" /-->
        <GridViewColumn Header="Health"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Monkey.Health}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Is Dead"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Monkey.IsDead}" />
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Models:

```
public class Monkey : Animal
{
  const int m_MinimumHealth = 30;

  public void CheckIsDead()
  {
    if (Health < m_MinimumHealth)
    {
      IsDead = true;
    }
    else IsDead = false;
  }
}

public class Animal
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
  }

  public float Health
  {
    get { return m_Health; }
    set
    {
      m_Health = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Health");
    }
  }

  public bool IsDead
  {
    get { return m_IsDead; }
    set
    {
      m_IsDead = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsDead");
    }
  }

  public int Index
  {
    get { return m_Index; }
    set
    {
      m_Index = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Index");
    }
  }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    MonkeyList = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      MonkeyList.Add(new Monkey {Index = i, Health = 100, IsDead = false});
    }

    OnPropertyChanged("MonkeyList");
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please delete your code comments. I've added them to your question.

Comment: Make sure you have an instance of MainWindowViewModel assigned to the DataContext of the MainWindow. Besides that, `Path=Monkey.Health` and `Path=Monkey.IsDead` should be `Path=Health` and `Path=IsDead`.

Comment: Thank you for organising it much better. BionicCode, for future reference what's the best way of doing this so it is readable when putting it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your ObservableCollection is not a property.  Common mistake...I just spent an hour yesterday dealing with that exact same issue.  XAML will ignore fields in your ViewModel, thus all bindings must be properties.  Define it thus:

```
public ObservableCollection<Monkey> MonkeyList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
```

Comment: How do you know that? The code in the question doesn't show the declaration of MonkeyList. Besides that, if you declare a property in a view model, either make it readonly (like `public ObservableCollection<Monkey> MonkeyList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();`) or fire the PropertyChanged event from its setter. The ObservableCollection class can **not** magically do that.

Comment: @Clemens, it is in the code...scroll down to the MainWindowViewModel.  It's the 5th line.  The ObseervibaleCollection was created specifically to raise the property changed notification event when the collection is  changed.  It's not magic, it's specifically designed to do so.  If you don't believe me, read the specification for yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Clemens, you're right about making it readonly though; this is good practice because the PropertyChanged event doesn't fire when you assign a new object to the OC property, it fires only when the collection changes.

Comment: That is not a local variable as you may assume. It is an assignment to a MonkeyList member which is declared elsewhere.

Comment: ah, I see what you're saying.  So what the heck is the view's DataContext?  By naming convention one can only assume its MainWindowViewModel.  Whatever the context, there needs to be a public property "MonkeyList" otherwise there's nothing to bind to.

Comment: Sure, that's why I wrote a comment on the question. For the other point, the PropertyChanged event doesn't fire because you didn't write the required code. For any settable property in a view model (no matter if it's an ObservableCollection or not), the property setter should fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Thank you guys, I knew it would be something simple. Making the observable collection a property was my missing piece.